# How can I mimic the GNU/linux C development environment on OSX Lion?

Tags: c, macos, development-environment

I just tried to write a simple C program on OSX Lion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");                                                                          
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc

```
$ gcc hello.c
test.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

Ok...fine

```
$ gcc -I /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What? Let's see...

```
$ gcc -I /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib test.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
```

Finally!

That seems like a lot of effort just to get a hello world working, how do I make gcc find libraries and header files in the MacOSX10.6.sdk directory by default like it does on linux?  On linux I find ldd and ldconfig quite useful, they don't seem to exist on OSX...is there an equivalent? What other useful tools are there for developing C on OSX?

Yes, I know xcode makes this easier, but suppose I wanted to use vim and the command line to work on an opensource c project.

Comment: As far as I know, your first attempt was supposed to work. It does work on my machine, at least.

Comment: I would try checking what xcode does, like which environment variables it sets and which options it passes to gcc and replicate that in the makefile. This way you just do `make` and voila.

Comment: @zneak I thought it would as well, and I vaguely remember it working before, but this is the first time I tried to compile any simple C programs since upgrading to OSX lion (10.7)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an OSX user, but some of the output of `gcc -v --help` might be helpful to those that are. But basically, as I'm sure you've guessed, it looks like a busted (or improperly setup) environment.

Comment: Add the result of "which gcc" to the information that others have already pointed out you should provide if you want others to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities:

1. You had 10.6 installed and upgraded to 10.7. You need to install the new version of Xcode (4.1, get it from the app store) to get back the developer tools.
2. you installed Xcode, did a custom install, and unchecked "UNIX development" or something. Rerun the installer and install the missing parts.
3. You installed a broken third-party version of gcc. Try `which gcc` and see what you get.

Comment: hm...not having xcode 4.1 might have been it...installing it now. I'll accept your answer if it fixes my environment :)

Comment: Yep, I feel like an idiot, didn't upgrade xcode when I upgraded to lion.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.7, if you have downloaded Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store and then run the installer that it downloads (in `/Applications`), your first attempt should have worked just fine assuming you have not set some environment variables that are looked at and influence Apple's `gcc` tool chain.  The object file that is produced in this case would be using the default 10.7 ABI (`include` files and libs).  If you want to produce something that would be compatible with OS X 10.6, then you need to tell the tool chain to use the 10.6 SDK ABI, which is what you did in the third attempt.  A standalone project typically handles this by setting up a Makefile to automate building.  But, unless you are trying to build something on a version of OS X (10.7 here) that will also run on earlier versions of OS X (say 10.6), there is generally no need to use an SDK.